# Register multiple implementations of same interface in Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Let's say I have component that currently has a single dependency on my interface `ICache` and is registered with a DB-based Cache implementation using constructor injection. Something like this:

```
container.Register(Component.For<ICache>()
                            .ImplementedBy<DatabaseCache>()
                            .LifeStyle.Singleton
                            .Named("dbcache"));
```

and then my component registers it:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IRepository>()
                            .ImplementedBy<CoolRepository>()
                            .LifeStyle.Singleton
                            .Named("repo")
                            .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(ICache), "dbcache")));
```

But what if I would like my component to be able to make use of a second `ICache` dependency of a different type at the same time? How would I inject 2 different implementations of the same interface into the main component?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the overload of `Dependency.OnComponent` that accepts a string as the first parameter.  This is the name of the parameter in the constructor for which the dependency will be supplied.  For example, if your `CoolRepository` constructor looks like this:

```
public CoolRepository(ICache first, ICache second)
{
    // ...
}
```

Then your registration will look like this:

```
// register another cache
container.Register(Component.For<ICache>()
                            .ImplementedBy<DummyCache>()
                            .LifeStyle.Singleton
                            .Named("otherCache"));

container.Register(Component.For<IRepository>()
                            .ImplementedBy<CoolRepository>()
                            .LifeStyle.Singleton
                            .Named("repo")
                            .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent("first", "dbcache"))
                            .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent("second", "otherCache")));
```

See more details [here](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/inline-dependencies.md#explicit-service-dependencies-dependencyoncomponent).

Comment: Cool, thank you Patrick, that worked perfectly, I was looking for some kind of overload to do what I was trying to do but I hadn't checked the overloads of OnComponent().